# Custom webpart with validation

Tags: validation

I want to build a custom form, with validation in SharePoint. Is there a built in library in SharePoint to validate required field, people pickers, choice fields, or do I need to use 3rd party javascript libraries? What do people use?

Answer (score 0):

In custom form webpart, you can create form using **Server side controls** (Asp.Net controls) as well as **HTML input controls**.

For validation, you can use either **server side validation rules** same as in .Net or **third party JavaScripts** (client side validation). If you are a hardcore developer then you can write custom **JavaScript/jQuery** codes as per your requirements.